# Realtime video buffer access webcam, Windows Phone 8.1 C++

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1, webcam

I need to do some basic video processing from the Webcam in Windows Phone 8.1.

I cannot find any examples of how to access the webcam preview buffer.  The Microsoft examples (very few) all have a video preview frame activate, I can find none that show how to subscribe to a 'new frame ready' event, or where the buffer is.

The MediaCapture, and CaptureDevice appear to be the main ways of reaching the camera in this api.

Can anyone point to a specific example?  For instance, a QR code reader, or maybe a program that adds video effects, like greyscale, would need to attach an event to every frame.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to access the buffer from the preview stream of the phone cameras. If you absolutely need to target 8 and 8.1, then you should look into `GetPreviewBufferArgb(out int[] pixels)`. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.media.capture.cameracaptureframe.getpreviewbufferargb.aspx

But if you can instead target Windows 10, you get the benefit of fully universal APIs, and you don't take a dependency on the likely soon to be deprecated (if not already) `Windows.Phone.Media.Capture` namespace. I would strongly recommend doing this instead, as the APIs will be easier to work with, and any 8.1 device can upgrade to 10 for free.

Here is a fully working Windows 10 sample: http://aka.ms/2015buildgetpreviewframesample, which was shown off at the last Build conference (video here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-730).

Comment: Thank-you very very much. I will try. I was putting off 10, because my carrier has blocked 10 dev preview (T-Mobile). So no device to test, and really the whole point in my case is to use it in a practical test. I'll try on the emulator, though I have no idea how developing 10 will be different.